# How to sharpen screen resolution in Android Studio?

Tags: performance, android-studio, screen-resolution

The image on the design screen suddenly started to become pixelated. How can I restore it to its original clear state?
[image]

Comment: Just a guess, but what happens if you click the "1:1" button? It looks like that's some scaling artifacts.

Comment: It zooms 100% and the text looks huge